# Java, listener advice, swing comp's

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe, jpanel

thanks for looking at this for me, heres my problems:

My If statement in my MyFrame class is saying "MyShape is abstract, cannot be instantiated"
i also do not know how to complete my actionlistener so that it creates a instance of the shape i chose from the jmenu. and lastly sets the dimension of my Jslider to the size and area of my sqaure and adds it to a JtextField.

1. how do i fix the error "MyShape is abstract, cannot be instantiated" ?
2. any tips on how to complete my if statement so that the shape i select is linked to my Jslider so it value is added to that shape ie a square or circle class?
3. how do i then out put the 2 methods on finding the legth and area of that class ie the square or circle to 2 Jtext fields?

I would love any help you can throw my way, if you can please explain what i need to do it a easy way for a noob at programming like me could understand :)

---

MyFrame

---

```
    package assignment;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


    public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public MyFrame() {


    // Create the menu
    JMenuBar topMenu = new JMenuBar();
    this.setJMenuBar(topMenu);

    //create the menu button "shapes"
    JMenu shapes = new JMenu("Shapes");
    topMenu.add(shapes);
    //Create the 3 shapes for the menu
    JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square");

    JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
    JMenuItem triangle = new JMenuItem("Triangle");

    //add shapes to menu
    shapes.add(circle);
    shapes.add(triangle);
    shapes.add(square);

    //add the menu
    setJMenuBar(topMenu);


    MyControlPanel pane = new MyControlPanel();
    this.add(pane);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    class squareAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JMenuItem clickedMenu = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
            if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Square")) {
                MyShape ASquare = new MyShape() {
                };
            } else if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Circle")) {
                MyShape Circle = new MyShape();
            } else if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Triangle")) {
                MyShape Triangle = new MyShape();
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

---

### Jpanel - MyControlPanel

```
    package assignment;

    //import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JSlider;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

    public class MyControlPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

JSlider slider;
JLabel sliderLabel;
JLabel sliderdimension;
JLabel blank;
JLabel dl;
JLabel area1;

/**
 * Creates new form MyControlPanel
 */
public MyControlPanel() {


    slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setValue(50);
    slider.addChangeListener(new MyChangeAction());
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setBounds(300, 50, 100, 50);

    sliderLabel = new JLabel("50");
    blank = new JLabel("     ");
    sliderdimension = new JLabel("Shape Dimension:");

    JTextField boundary_length = new JTextField("Boundary Length");
    JTextField area = new JTextField("Area");

    dl = new JLabel("Boundary Length =");
    area1 = new JLabel("Area =");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
    sliderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 0));


    sliderPanel.add(sliderdimension);
    sliderPanel.add(sliderLabel);
    sliderPanel.add(slider);
    sliderPanel.add(dl);
    sliderPanel.add(boundary_length);
    sliderPanel.add(area1);
    sliderPanel.add(area);
    this.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   

public class MyChangeAction implements ChangeListener {

    //complete code here
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
        int value = slider.getValue();
        String str = Integer.toString(value);
        sliderLabel.setText(str);


    }
    } // end class
    }
```

---

MyShape

---

```
    package assignment;

    public abstract class MyShape
 {

double thelength;
double thearea;



public abstract double computeBoundaryLength(double Length);

public abstract double computeArea (double Length);
 }
```

---

ASquare

---

```
    package assignment;

    public class ASquare extends MyShape {

@Override
public double computeBoundaryLength(double Length) 
{
    thelength=(4*Length);
    return thelength;
}

@Override
public double computeArea(double Length) 
{
    thearea=(Length*Length);
    return thearea;
}

}
```

---

class shapeAction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

```
            JMenuItem clickedMenu = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
            if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Square")){
                 //implement abstract methods
            MyShape ASquare = new ASquare();  
            ASquare.addActionListener(new shapeAction());
            }
            else if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Circle")){ 
                 //implement abstract methods
                MyShape ACircle = new ACircle();
            ACircle.addActionListener(new shapeAction());
            }
            else if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Triangle")){ 
                 //implement abstract methods
                MyShape ATriangle = new ATriangle();
            ATriangle.addActionListener(new shapeAction());
```

Comment: *"if you can please explain what i need to do it a easy way for a noob"*  1) Ask a question.  2) Check the preview of your post.  3/4 of those code listings fail to include the closing `}`.  Posts can be edited.

Comment: 3) include less code. I seriously doubt the actual implementations of most of the methods are any important.

Comment: i have fixed my MyShape ASquare = new ASquare(); any tips of the rest? im finding this hard :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `squareAction` is meant to be the class that listens to all the possible menu selections (one for each kind of shape), so it shoud be named `ShapeMenuAction` or something like that. If you want `ShapeMenuAction`'s `actionPerformed` to be executed when a menu option is selected, you have create one instance of it and add it to each `MenuItem` with `addActionListener` method on them. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

In MyFrame:

```
JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square");
square.addActionListener(new ShapeAction());
JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
circle.addActionListener(new ShapeAction());
JMenuItem triangle = new JMenuItem("Triangle");
triangle.addActionListener(new ShapeAction());
```

- Inside your `actionPerformed` you have to instantiate a concrete subclass of `MyShape`. Now you are doing nothing but instantiating a shape, you have to do something with the object before the method ends, right?. Create a `setShape` method in your `MyControlPanel` and call it from actionPerformed, passing the newly created shape to it.

In ShapeAction:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       JMenuItem clickedMenu = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
       if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Square")) {
           MyShape aSquare = new ASquare();
           myControlPanel.setShape(aSquare);
       } else if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Circle")) {
           MyShape aCircle = new ACircle();
           myControlPanel.setShape(aCircle);             
       } else if (clickedMenu.getText().equals("Triangle")) {                 
           MyShape aTriangle = new MyShape();  
           myControlPanel.setShape(aTriangle);           
       }         
    }
```

You have to create a MyControPanel named myControlPanel in MyFrame:

```
private MyControlPanel myControlPanel
```

and add it with

```
myControlPanel = new MyControlPanel();
getContentPane().add(myControlPanel);
```

before

```
pack();
```

- In `MyControlPanel` now you can update your labels according to the slider value and the selected shape, everytime one of them changes.

  private MyShape shape;
  public void set Shape(MyShape shape) {
     this.shape = shape;
     updateLabels();
  }

Comment: No, you have to add it in MyFrame, with square.addActionListener(new ShapeAction()); after the menu item has been created. The same for circle and triangle menu options.

Comment: Create a setShape method in your MyControlPanel and call it from actionPerformed, passing the newly created shape to it. is it-  public setShape(){ } then what?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to write:

```
   MyShape circle = new ASquare();
   MyShape triangle = new ASquare();
```

in place of :

```
    MyShape circle = new MyShape();
```

MyShape triangle  = new MyShape();

If you are trying to implement new inline classes for `circle` and `triangle`, you may want to write:

```
   MyShape circle = new MyShape (){
      //implement abstract methods
   }

   MyShape triangle = new MyShape (){
      //implement abstract methods
   }
```

Comment: @StevenMcilhone I would say, define `MyControlPanel pane = null;` as a class variable in `MyFrame` class. Expose `slider` in `MyControlPanel` trough a getter method.  Once done, you will have access of `pane` inside you `if` block, simply get the `slider` and add the object created. If you need code example, please let me know.

Comment: how do i add a actionlistener to JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square"); so that the menu knows what shape is being selected

Comment: @StevenMcilhone After lines like this `JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square");`, add the listeners as `square.addActionListener(new squareAction());`. This you can do for each of your menu items.

Comment: thank you, but does that mean i need to add any code to the ASquare class or Myshape?

Comment: @StevenMcilhone No. `ASquare` is real class. Even when you say, `MyShape triangle = new ASquare();`, `triangle` is `ASquare` only.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't lie—you need to use concrete classes. Abstract class types themselves cannot be instantiated, so you can use this:

```
MyShape aSquare = new ASquare();
```

but not this:

```
MyShape aSquare = new MyShape ();
```

similarly if you have you have concrete circle & triangle available:

```
MyShape circle = new MyCircle();
...
MyShape triangle = new MyTriangle();
```

Answer (score 2):

The message indicates that `MyShape` is `abstract` so you can not instantiate it:

It's defined to be abstract:

```
public abstract class MyShape {
```

which means you can not do

```
new MyShape(); //compilation error
```

Always remember you cannot instantiate abstract classes and interfaces in Java.

You can instantiate concrete classes which are neither abstract nor an interface.